# Building gdcm-2.4.3 with CMake 3.2.2

Tags: cmake, dicom, gdcm

I have previously downloaded gdcm-2.4.3 and built it using CMake with the following command.

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 10 2010 Win64" ..\gdcm-2.4.3
```

Which worked fine. I now want to repeat this but now it says it can't find a bunch of header files (sys/time.h, lanfinfo, pthread.h etc - all very Unix-y) and the build fails.

Is there a step I'm missing? I thought I noted everything down last time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably OK to ignore.  It's using the [`CheckIncludeFiles`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/CheckIncludeFiles.html) CMake module to check for the existence of these files and that module outputs a message to show whether it found the file or not.

If there are any actual hard errors while running CMake, there will be output to show this and ultimately the .sln won't be produced.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what's going on and the .sln is successfully generated.